# Should [history] and [cinema-history] really be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) currently redirects to [cinema-history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history). I think they should not be synonyms.

[cinema-history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history) questions clearly should ask about the history of cinema and movies in general, how film technology evolved and what happened in what era. That in fact matches the  content of the questions currently tagged this way.

[history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) however should in my opinion be reserved for questions regarding historical movies, meaning it should be a genre tag along the lines of [horror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror), [thriller](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller) and [comedy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy).

Instinctively I would tag new questions for movies like Alexander, 300 or Gladiator with the history tag, which would be wrong under the current configuration.

The ambiguity between the two tags could be resolved by writing helptexts for both tags that clearly define the scope.

What do you think? Should [history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [cinema-history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history) really be synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

No, I do not think they should be synonyms. I agree with your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I have reversed this for the time being.  That was my doing as I could not see many *history* related questions being written here, but you do make a good point.

Comment: It still shows up as synonyms for me. Or does it take time to update?

Comment: As it turns out I'm an idiot and never finalized it, should be done now :p